# Custom Query in Elementor Pro not working

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I have a custom post type 'properties' which has a checkbox field (fieldname 'property_status') with the options 'rent : For rent' and 'sale : For sale' (value : label). I also have a page where I want to list all the properties that are for sale, so there I have added the posts widget and gave the query the ID 'for-sale'. I checked the custom query documentation at https://developers.elementor.com/custom-query-filter/ and in my child theme's functions.php I have added the following lines:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/for-sale', function( $query ) {
    // Get current meta Query
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

    // Append our meta query
    $meta_query = [
        'key'       => 'property_status',
        'value'     => 'sale',
        'compare'   => 'in',
    ];
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query);
} );
```

This does not produce the results I wanted: it does not break my site, but I keep on getting a list of *all* of the properties. Just to test things, I also tried this code with other field types (text field & number field) and other comparison operators but with the same results. I also commented the lines above and entered the following line:

```
$query->set( 'post_type', 'agent' );
```

This does indeed give me a list of agents instead of properties, so at least I know the add_action is doing its work, which is worth something I suppose. Does anyone have any suggestions perhaps as to how I can adjust that meta query so that it actually works? I'm not a PHP developer, and not quite sure how to proceed from here. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. I really would like to learn what I am doing wrong, as it would give me the opportunity to take my sites a little bit further.

Comment: the code of compare is not `  'compare'   => '='  `  but  `'compare' => 'in' ` i think

Comment: Yes, you are right -that was a sloppy copy&past from one of my tryouts. My first version was actually with 'in' but when that did not work, I tried '='. I have updated my question in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Also you're not appending the property_status query to the rest of the meta_query. You're simply just copying it into it. You could use Array_push